# How to access ambiguous UIViewController in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I currently have a UIPageController that is showing view controllers in a subview, the UIViewController in the UIPageController is populated from an array using the following code:

```
UIViewController * childViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[_viewControllers objectAtIndex:index]];
```

The only issue now is I can't access or assign values to the properties of the view controller I have just instantiated from the array because it's being dynamically allocated, I'm wondering if trying to cast the childViewController to its right view controller would work but I'm not too sure how I'd go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is you have a custom UIViewController subclass, but when you instantiate one using the code you posted it is cast as a vanilla UIViewController and you can't use your custom methods.

You can cast it like this:

`MyCustomController * childViewController = (MyCustomController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[_viewControllers objectAtIndex:index]];`

Then you will be able to access all of the custom methods of `MyCustomController`. Also, make sure you've imported the header for your custom controller class.

Comment: Can I assign/access the view controllers properties as well doing this?

Comment: Yes, once you have cast the controller as your custom subclass all of the subclass's properties and methods will be available. You will be able to run `[childViewController setCustomProperty]` and `[childViewController customProperty]`.